# Unable to use RadioSelect buttons in Django to get an output

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to create a site which takes in user input in form of RadiSelect buttons, and based on that button, a query has to be run on the database and results to be displayed.

Here is the html:

```html
    {% block content %}
       <div class="container">
       <h1>Welcome to your page, @{{ user.username }}</h1>
       <h3>Select vendor to check your balance!</h3>
       <br>
    <form method="POST" class="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap_form form %}
        {% buttons %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Check Balance</button>
        {% endbuttons %}
    </form>
    {% if args.model %}
       <h4>You need to pay Rs {{ args.model }} to vendor {{ args.choice }}    
       </h4>

        {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

The urls.py:

```py
    from django.urls import path
    from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
    from . import views

    app_name = 'profiles'

    urlpatterns = [
        path('adminKaLogin/', views.adminKaPage, name="adminHome"),
        path('userLogin/', views.userKaLog, name="userHome"),
    ]
```

The forms.py

```py
    from django import forms
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

    vendor_choices = [
        ('1','Vendor 1'),('2',"Vendor 2"), ("3", "Vendor 3"),
    ]    

    class select_vendor_form(forms.Form):
        Vendor_choices = forms.ChoiceField(choices=vendor_choices,
                                    widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

The views.py

```py
    def userKaLog(request):
        form = select_vendor_form()
        if request.method=="POST" and form.is_valid():
            choice = form.cleaned_data['Vendor_choices']
            print(choice)
            records = userData.objects.get(Vendor_number = ('choice')).aggregate(Sum('itemPrice'))
            args = {'form': form, 'choice': choice, 'model':records}
            return render(request, 'profiles/useLogin.html', args)
        else:
            return render(request, 'profiles/userLogin.html', {'form': form})
```

The models.py:

```py
    from django.db import models
    from datetime import datetime
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User 

    class userData(models.Model):
        name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        balance = models.IntegerField()
        date_of_payment = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now())
        vendor_number  = models.IntegerField()
```

If the person selects radio button of vendor 1, the output should be the total money owed to vendor 1 by that user. I am unable to get where I am going wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please always include your code in the question, **not** as images.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, the form never gets the POST data. Be sure to feed the data to the form in order for it to have valid results. You can do that in your view as follows:

```
def userKaLog(request):
  form = select_vendor_form()
  # Check if the current method was a POST method
  if request.method=="POST":
    # Initiate the form again, but with post data
    form = select_vendor_form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      choice = form.cleaned_data['Vendor_choices']
      choice = int(choice)
      records = userData.objects.get(Vendor_number = choice).aggregate(Sum('itemPrice'))
      args = {'form': form, 'choice': choice, 'model':records}
      return render(request, 'profiles/useLogin.html', args)

  # Return the normal results, form will display an error message if POST was triggered
  return render(request, 'profiles/userLogin.html', {'form': form})
```

You can read more about forms here: [The Django Forms API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/)

It could be that there is also something going wrong in your userData retrieval as in your current models file there is no itemPrice. So you may need to check that too.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs! I never really realised that we need to renew the form again with the POST data. Why are we doing this though? Also, another error is popping up now : **invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'choice'**  . What could be the reason?

Comment: Well, for your question about renewing the form. when you initiate a form without any input (i.e. form = MyForm() ) the form is created without any input data. It is not aware of any of the input the user send by pressing submit. It's like saying adress = StoreAdress() . The instance adress knows it is a type of store adress, but in which city, street... That's why we need to send along some data. In this case just a simple argument of request.POST.

Comment: Why we initiate it again has a more visual reason. When a form is not valid, it will show errors on the page. However, by not giving any input data, the form assumes that no data was ever given, i.e. the page is displayed for the first time. It prevents the webpage from displaying errors the first time you load the webpage.
If you don't want to reload form twice. You might want to look into View classes, but that's a story for another time.

Comment: Finally, in my code I only adressed your  form post problem. Though I now see you also had a different problem: you try to get a model object the wrong way. Instead  of
    Vendor_number = ('choice')
You should've just called your variable:
    Vendor_number = choice
I fixed my code above so you can see the difference.
Basically, it expected an integer value (the vendor number), but instead got a string 'choice'.